# SQL - Grouping SQL output in 5 minute intervals

Tags: sql

I have a dataset that has a date column every 1 minute.
I wanted to group the information to have the data "organized" every 5 minutes and average the SellCount column.

For example, I have 5 records, 1 for minute 1, another for minute 2, another for minute 3, another for minute 4 and finally another for minute 5. I want to group in a single line where the date is present will be the 5th minute.

I send the code to create the table and insert the data.

```
CREATE TABLE SELL (ProductID int,Description varchar(10),Timestamp_int  int, SellCount  int,Timestamp_datetime datetime)

INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430060,1,'2023-02-15 03:01:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430120,2,'2023-02-15 03:02:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430180,0,'2023-02-15 03:03:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430240,2,'2023-02-15 03:04:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430300,5,'2023-02-15 03:05:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430360,4,'2023-02-15 03:06:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430420,3,'2023-02-15 03:07:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430480,1,'2023-02-15 03:08:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430540,1,'2023-02-15 03:09:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430600,1,'2023-02-15 03:10:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430660,0,'2023-02-15 03:11:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430720,0,'2023-02-15 03:12:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430780,0,'2023-02-15 03:13:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430840,7,'2023-02-15 03:14:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(1,'Coke',1676430900,1,'2023-02-15 03:15:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430060,1,'2023-02-15 03:01:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430120,3,'2023-02-15 03:02:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430180,5,'2023-02-15 03:03:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430240,2,'2023-02-15 03:04:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430300,1,'2023-02-15 03:05:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430360,1,'2023-02-15 03:06:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430420,1,'2023-02-15 03:07:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430480,2,'2023-02-15 03:08:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430540,2,'2023-02-15 03:09:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430600,2,'2023-02-15 03:10:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430660,6,'2023-02-15 03:11:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430720,5,'2023-02-15 03:12:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430780,3,'2023-02-15 03:13:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430840,1,'2023-02-15 03:14:00.000')
INSERT INTO SELL VALUES(2,'7 Up',1676430900,2,'2023-02-15 03:15:00.000')
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC6Qp.png)

Comment: Please format your question, and what is your output and what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a very trivial answer.  Lets get the number of minutes since epoch (zero), divide/multiple by five to round down to nearest five minutes and add back minutes to epoch to get newly created time.

```
-- buck date time by 5 mins, sum by total count    
select  
      dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, timestamp_datetime) / 5 * 5, 0) as round_five,
      sum(sellcount) as total_cnt
    from 
      stackoverflow.dbo.sell
    group by 
      dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, timestamp_datetime) / 5 * 5, 0)
```

The output from SQL Server Management Studio is shown below.

[image]

If you want to know by product by time interval, just add to grouping.  In short, easy peassy!

Comment: Hi,
This is not how I want to group.
Records containing date between minute 01 to minute 05 per product must group to date HH:05:SS.
Records containing date between minute 06 to minute 10 by product must group to date HH:10:SS.

Comment: So change the formula so that anything mod 5 > 0 becomes the next number.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `cte` and floor division by `5` to group each row into its five minute block:

```
with cte as (
   select s.*, floor(timestampdiff(minute, (select min(s1.Timestamp_datetime) 
      from SELL s1 where s1.ProductID = s.ProductID), s.Timestamp_datetime)/5) r_id 
   from SELL s
)
select t.ProductID, c.Description, t.av, t.mt, t.mdt from (
   select c.ProductID, c.r_id, sum(c.SellCount)/count(*) av, max(c.Timestamp_int) mt, 
          max(c.Timestamp_datetime) mdt 
   from cte c group by c.ProductID, c.r_id) t
join cte c on c.ProductID = t.ProductID and c.r_id = t.r_id and c.Timestamp_datetime = t.mdt
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NYxLXeYv)

Comment: Hi,
My development is in SQL 2017, the timestampdiff function is not available. It is only available in MySQL. Is there another way?

Comment: @user3303981 Yes, simply swap out `timestampdiff` for `datediff`: https://dbfiddle.uk/XO_66hoM

Answer (score 0):

A simple SELECT gets the job done

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, DESCRIPTION, group_id, SUM(SELLCOUNT)/COUNT(1) AS AVG_SELLCOUNT, FROM_UNIXTIME(group_id)
FROM (
   SELECT a.*, 300*(1+FLOOR((TIMESTAMP_INT-1)/300)) group_id FROM SELL a
) b
GROUP BY PRODUCTID, DESCRIPTION, group_id
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

The `300` value can be replaced by any other value in seconds and it will reflect the data granularity.

I used the data provided in the request in the working example available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/967a15/15)